# how to change the layout theme color using framework7?

Tags: css, html-framework-7

I want to change the body color dynamically using framework7. I tried including framework7.css and framework7.js files but it doesn't work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/framework7.material.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/framework7.material.colors.css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/kitchen-sink.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/framework7.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/kitchen-sink.js"></script>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?  What do you mean by it doesn't work ? Are you getting an error ?

Comment: i have a color-themes page, in which there are three div ,containing different background color, i want when we click on a div then the color of body is changed according to the div. i want this happen with the help of framework7,but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### CSS

In your css you should define the classes for the background colors. For example, `yellow-background`, `red-background` and `bluebackground`.

```
.yellow-background {    
    background: yellow;
}
etc.
```

#### JS

Then in your javascript the class should be added or removed based on the click of the button. Something like this:

```
$$('.some-button').on('click', function (e) {
    $$('.some-div').removeClass('yellow-background');
    $$('.some-div').removeClass('blue-background'); 

    $$('.some-div').addClass('red-background'); 
}
```

Comment: yes, you are right, but i want to done this thing with the help of framework7, not with jquery.

Comment: This IS Framework7. It works very similar to jquery. jquery uses a single `$` and Framework7 uses double `$$`. Check  [link](http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/dom.html#.VjCl8PlVhHw) for more details

Answer (score 1):

I have created my custom color theme in Framework7 by creating css file into which I have copied the part of `framework7.ios.colors.css` responsible for creating red theme color. Replaced `red` with my custom color, which is `opco`.

The same I did for hex color `#ff3b30` to `#cbcc33`. Don't forget to search and replace for phrase `ff3b30` because SVG elements won't have their color changed.

When doing so, don't forget to include your newly created .css file into your html by:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom-color-theme.css">
```

My css file with working custom color theme for Framework7:

```
.color-opco {
  color: #cbcc33;
}
.list-block .item-link.list-button.color-opco,
.tabbar a.active.color-opco,
a.color-opco {
  color: #cbcc33;
}
.label-switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .checkbox.color-opco,
.label-switch.color-opco input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .checkbox {
  background-color: #cbcc33;
}
.color-opco.button:not(.button-fill),
.color-opco.buttons-row .button,
.theme-opco .button:not(.button-fill) {
  border-color: #cbcc33;
}
html:not(.watch-active-state) .color-opco.button:not(.button-fill):active,
html:not(.watch-active-state) .color-opco.buttons-row .button:active,
html:not(.watch-active-state) .theme-opco .button:not(.button-fill):active,
.color-opco.button:not(.button-fill).active-state,
.color-opco.buttons-row .button.active-state,
.theme-opco .button:not(.button-fill).active-state {
  background-color: rgba(255, 59, 48, 0.15);
}
.color-opco.button:not(.button-fill).active,
.color-opco.buttons-row .button.active,
.theme-opco .button:not(.button-fill).active {
  background-color: #cbcc33;
  color: #fff;
}
.theme-opco .button.button-fill,
.button.button-fill.color-opco {
  background: #cbcc33;
  color: #fff;
}
.progressbar.color-opco span,
.progressbar.theme-opco span,
.theme-opco .progressbar span,
.progressbar.bg-opco span {
  background-color: #cbcc33;
}
.progressbar-infinite.color-opco:before,
.progressbar-infinite.theme-opco:before,
.theme-opco .progressbar-infinite:before,
.progressbar-infinite.bg-opco:before {
  background-color: #cbcc33;
}
.color-opco i.icon,
.theme-opco i.icon,
i.icon.color-opco,
i.icon.theme-opco {
  color: #cbcc33;
}
i.icon-next.color-opco,
i.icon-next.theme-opco,
.theme-opco i.icon-next {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2015%2015'%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D'%23cbcc33'%20d%3D'M1%2C1.6l11.8%2C5.8L1%2C13.4V1.6%20M0%2C0v15l15-7.6L0%2C0L0%2C0z'%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}
i.icon-prev.color-opco,
i.icon-prev.theme-opco,
.theme-opco i.icon-prev {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2015%2015'%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D'%23cbcc33'%20d%3D'M14%2C1.6v11.8L2.2%2C7.6L14%2C1.6%20M15%2C0L0%2C7.6L15%2C15V0L15%2C0z'%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}
i.icon-back.color-opco,
i.icon-back.theme-opco,
.theme-opco i.icon-back {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2012%2020'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M10%2C0l2%2C2l-8%2C8l8%2C8l-2%2C2L0%2C10L10%2C0z'%20fill%3D'%23cbcc33'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}
i.icon-forward.color-opco,
i.icon-forward.theme-opco,
.theme-opco i.icon-forward {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2012%2020'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M2%2C20l-2-2l8-8L0%2C2l2-2l10%2C10L2%2C20z'%20fill%3D'%23cbcc33'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}
i.icon-bars.color-opco,
i.icon-bars.theme-opco,
.theme-opco i.icon-bars {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2021%2014'%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D'%23cbcc33'%20d%3D'M0%2C0h2v2H0V0z%20M4%2C0h17v1H4V0z%20M0%2C6h2v2H0V6z%20M4%2C6h17v1H4V6z%20M0%2C12h2v2H0V12z%20M4%2C12h17v1H4V12z'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  i.icon-bars.color-opco,
  i.icon-bars.theme-opco,
  .theme-opco i.icon-bars {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2042%2026'%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D'%23cbcc33'%20d%3D'M0%2C0h4v4H0V0z%20M8%2C1h34v2H8V1z%20M0%2C11h4v4H0V11z%20M8%2C12h34v2H8V12z%20M0%2C22h4v4H0V22z%20M8%2C23h34v2H8V23z'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
  }
}
.theme-opco a,
.theme-opco .item-link.list-button {
  color: #cbcc33;
}
.theme-opco .tabbar a,
.tabbar.theme-opco a,
.theme-opco .tabbar a i,
.tabbar.theme-opco a i {
  color: inherit;
}
.theme-opco .tabbar a.active,
.tabbar.theme-opco a.active,
.theme-opco .tabbar a.active i,
.tabbar.theme-opco a.active i {
  color: #cbcc33;
}
.theme-opco .range-slider input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:before,
.range-slider.theme-opco input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:before {
  background-color: #cbcc33;
}
.theme-opco .range-slider input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower,
.range-slider.theme-opco input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background-color: #cbcc33;
}
.theme-opco label.label-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .item-media i.icon-form-checkbox,
.theme-opco label.label-checkbox input[type="radio"]:checked + .item-media i.icon-form-checkbox {
  background-color: #cbcc33;
}
.theme-opco label.label-radio input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .item-inner,
.theme-opco label.label-radio input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .item-inner {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2013%2010'%3E%3Cpolygon%20fill%3D'%23cbcc33'%20points%3D'11.6%2C0%204.4%2C7.2%201.4%2C4.2%200%2C5.6%204.4%2C10%204.4%2C10%204.4%2C10%2013%2C1.4%20'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}
.theme-opco .picker-calendar-day.picker-calendar-day-selected span {
  background-color: #cbcc33 !important;
}
.swiper-pagination.color-opco .swiper-pagination-bullet-active,
.theme-opco .swiper-pagination .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background-color: #cbcc33;
}
.swiper-pagination.color-opco .swiper-pagination-progressbar,
.theme-opco .swiper-pagination .swiper-pagination-progressbar {
  background-color: #cbcc33;
}
.swiper-pagination.swiper-pagination-progress.bg-opco {
  background-color: rgba(255, 59, 48, 0.25);
}
.swiper-button-next.color-opco,
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-prev.color-opco,
.theme-opco .swiper-button-next,
.theme-opco .swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-prev {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M27%2C22L27%2C22L5%2C44l-2.1-2.1L22.8%2C22L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23cbcc33'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}
.swiper-button-prev.color-opco,
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-next.color-opco,
.theme-opco .swiper-button-prev,
.theme-opco .swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-next {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M0%2C22L22%2C0l2.1%2C2.1L4.2%2C22l19.9%2C19.9L22%2C44L0%2C22L0%2C22L0%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23cbcc33'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}
.bg-opco,
.button.button-fill.bg-opco,
a.bg-opco,
.list-block .swipeout-actions-left a.bg-opco,
.list-block .swipeout-actions-right a.bg-opco {
  background-color: #cbcc33;
}
.border-opco {
  border-color: #cbcc33;
}
.list-block .border-opco.item-inner:after,
.list-block ul.border-opco:after,
.border-opco:after,
.list-block .border-opco.item-inner:before,
.list-block ul.border-opco:before,
.border-opco:before {
  background-color: #cbcc33;
}
.badge.color-opco,
.badge.theme-opco {
  background-color: #cbcc33;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple.
If you don't know how to use DOM functions.
Please check it once => 
Click [framework7-DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49087044/css-selector-in-framework7-vue/56058124#56058124)!

or

If you are familiar with dom just change any CSS just like:

```
$$('.classname').css({
    left: '100px',
    top: '200px',
    color: 'red',
    width: '300px',
    marginLeft: '17px',
   'padding-right': '20px'
});
```

You can use all the CSS attributes here as you can show in the code.
You don't need to add or remove classes at all.

But if there is already added 'important' on that class which you want to change the color,
just change CSS as:

```
   this.$$('.appbg').attr('style', 'background-color: green !important');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your custom color for background or text. Add your color to framework7.material.colors.css :

```
//your custom background
.layout-bg-custom {
  background-color: #fff;
}
//custom text color
.color-custom {
  color: #ec325b;
}
//custom framework7 buttons
.theme-custom .button.button-fill {
   background: #ec325b;
   color: #fff;
}
```

Similary you can add color to different tags, Then in HTML add the above class to the tag you want that css to be applied.

```
<button class="button button-fill theme-custom">F7 Footer button</button>
```

Framework7 already provide with some theme colors (you can also add to these themes) : http://framework7.io/docs/color-themes.html