# Css Selector in Framework7 vue

Tags: css, cordova, dom, vue.js, html-framework-7

i try to build an Cordova/Phonegap application using vue.js and the Framework7.
I find out how to use functions like "onClick" using the "v-on:click="OnClick" attribute in an html element. Framework7 has jquery already implemented in the dom.

But there is one question. How can i access the dom directly, so that i can select whole css classes with the jquery selector. Like:
`$('.likeButton')`. ?

In the offical framework7 i found something like this to access the dom with its functions:

```
this.$$ or this.Dom7
```

This is what i have already written down in the home.vue file:

```
    <script>


  //import Fonts-awesome Icons
  import FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
  import {} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid'
  import F7Icon from "framework7-vue/src/components/icon";
  import F7PageContent from "framework7-vue/src/components/page-content";
  import * as Framework7 from "framework7";

  export default {
    name: 'FAExample',

    components: {
      F7PageContent,
      F7Icon,
      FontAwesomeIcon
    },
    methods: {
      clickit: function () {
        console.log("hi");

        //this is what i have tested, looking if i have access to dom
        let $$ = this.$$;
        console.log($$);
      },
      //this is what i want to use
      $('.likebutton').on('click',function () {

  })
  }


  }


</script>
```

Did any of you have an idea how this works?
I hope you can help me. I'm new with vue.js in combination with the framework7.

Thank's for your help :)

Comment: You don't want to use `v-on` because you want to hook the same function to all `.likebutton`s? If not, why not use `v-on`, then?

Comment: People still trying to integrate jQuery when they are new to Vue.js. You don't need that! Like you said: Use `v-on:click="myMethod"` or shorter: `@click="myMethod"`.

Comment: Not jQuery, but Dom7. $$('.likebutton').on('click', function (e) {
  console.log('clicked');
});

Answer (score 1):

We can use all the DOM functions just like

```
this.$$('.classname)
```

for example, if you want to hide something by jquery you can use as:

```
this.$$('.classname).hide()
```

To check all the DOM functions you can check the official documentation. 
https://framework7.io/docs/dom7.html

But make sure that your DOM function should not in any Window function.
If you get the error to implemented it, just make the 'this' instance first.

Just like:
var self=this; // a global variable with this instance
use

```
self.$$('.classname).hide()
```

for any framework7 help, just ping me on skyp: sagardhiman5_1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Vue's `$refs`? You can set a reference to a specific DOM element and then access that in Vue.

A simple example:

```
<template>
  <div class="some-item" ref="itemRef">Some item</div>
</template>
```

Then in the component:

```
var myItem = this.$refs.myItem;
// do what you want with that DOM item...
```

You can also access $refs from the parent. The example in the link below gives details on that.

More on $refs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs